# Insert each array item in separate field

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked thoroughly, but I have not found the solution (or perhaps I didn't realize I had since I'm a novice)... Here is my problem:

My table has these six fields: username,want1,want2,want3,want4,want5. My form has username, and a multiple SELECT box where five wishes are selected. I want to insert that username and those selections together as a record, in their corresponding "cell" in the table. Here is my code (for the submit/$_POST action) so far:

*Note: I have named the multiple SELECT box "wants[]" so that it knows it's an array.

```
<?php
//variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$want = $_POST['wants'];
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
//insert 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO The_Table (username,want1,want2,want3,want4,want5) VALUES ('$username','$want[0]','$want[1]','$want[2]','$want[3]','$want[4]')");
?>
```

When I test, no bugs/errors show, but the table isn't being filled with a record. I am very new to coding, I apologize. Hopefully there is a simple solution. Thank you so much to any help or advice!!

Comment: stop making new code with mysql-* function instead of it use PDO or mysqli

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code i hope its work for you...

> form.php

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" name="form">
user_name : <input name="u_name" type="text" /><br />
wish 1 : <input name="wish_1" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br />
wish 2 : <input name="wish_2" type="checkbox" value="2"/><br />
wish 3 : <input name="wish_3" type="checkbox" value="3"/><br />
wish 4 : <input name="wish_4" type="checkbox" value="4"/><br />
wish 5 : <input name="wish_5" type="checkbox" value="5"/><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

> insert.php

```
<?php
//variables
$username = isset($_POST['u_name'])?$_POST['u_name']:'';
$wish_1   = isset($_POST['wish_1'])?$_POST['wish_1']:'';
$wish_2   = isset($_POST['wish_2'])?$_POST['wish_2']:'';
$wish_3   = isset($_POST['wish_3'])?$_POST['wish_3']:'';
$wish_4   = isset($_POST['wish_4'])?$_POST['wish_4']:'';
$wish_5   = isset($_POST['wish_5'])?$_POST['wish_5']:'';
//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
//insert 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO The_Table (username,want1,want2,want3,want4,want5) 
VALUES ('".$username."','".$wish_1."','".$wish_2."'
,'".$wish_3."','".$wish_4."','".$wish_5."')");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I bet it would work. However, (and perhaps I should have said this) eventually I want to have an auto-fill select box with perhaps a thousand or more options in the want box, and you can select up to 20. Thus I don't believe checkboxes will be very ideal for the situation. Right now I'm just keeping it small, and will extrapolate it once it's working. Thank you so much for the suggestion though! I am continuing to search for a solution

Answer (score 0):

In your description, you say you named the select "wishes" and the fields "wish1", "wish2" etc., but then in your code you call it ['wants'] and "want1, want2".  If that's really how your code is, it would cause a problem...

Comment: It's all want, I just typed it wrong oops. Thanks for the heads up!